# Asset files are not being loaded even though server is serving them

Tags: javascript, browser, server, clojure, compojure

I've setup a minimal web server with `compojure` like this:

```
(defroutes m-routes
           (GET "/index.html" []
             {:status 200
              :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
              :body (slurp "resources/index.html")})
           (GET "/style.css" []
             {:status 200
              :headers {"Content-Type" "text/css"}
              :body (slurp "resources/style.css")})
           (GET "/index.js" []
             {:status 200
              :headers {"Content-Type" "application/javascript"}
              :body (slurp "resources/index.js")})
           (GET "*" []
             "nothing here"))
```

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=mapReady">
    </script>
    <div id="toast"></div>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can `GET` all the resource files if I try to access them from the browser, but for some reason, they aren't being loaded by the main page `index.html`. I can tell because no styling is being applied to the elements. There are no errors in the console. How should I get this server working?

Comment: Have you checked the "Network" tab in the developer tools to see if the HTTP request for the CSS file is being made?

Comment: you should not use relative links, if index.js is located the webroot then set src="/index.js" it rather looks as it is in src="/resources/index.js" ?

Comment: I would guess that your paths are wrong and you're getting 404s for those files. As Pointy said check the network tab in devtools.